# How to identify the UIKeyboard predictive text selection action?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard, uicontrol

I'm working on custom UIControl where I will be opening a keyboard(The custom control is become a first responder). In this case I want to identify or detect the which suggested keyword been selected or tapped on the keyboard, so how can I do this?
[image]

Comment: After doing so much work around I found there is now way to get direct action of predictive text buttons from UIKeyboard. But, found some alternate solution from https://github.com/JayachandraA/swift_ui_keyinput.git